# How to get the information that throttling limit has been reached?

Tags: apache-camel, throttling

Inside a Camel route, I need to throttle the messages when a limit of request/s is reached. I've found the Throttler EIP. It works fine but I need when the limit is reached to raise an alert, is there a way to do this ?

I had a look at the code but don't found a way to extend it.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to know out of the box. You would need to extend it, or build your own throttler.

I logged a ticket so we can expose in JMX the number of messages currently hold-back throttler: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6670

If your altering tooling can react on JMX then they can react if the jmx attribute > 0 and send an email etc.

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick response. But If I extend it, how can I invoke it inside my camel route knowing that I'm using the DSL format ?

Comment: I mean replace **from().throttle(100).to()** by **from().mythrottle(100).to()**

Comment: All EIPs in Camel is a Processor. So you can extend the code and use a .process in the DSL, eg from XX process(new MyThrottler(100)).to YY

Comment: Ok thank you Claus. In fact I was already aware of this kind of invocation. The problem is that I had a look at the **ThrottlerDefinition** class and it seems that it does not use the default  constructor to instanciate it. So I don't know how to pass all the needed input to the Throttler such as the context and so on ...  I hope I was clear enough :-)